# Should I capitalize a quoted transliteration?

Tags: capitalization, transliteration, quoting

Consider the following:

> "Saranghe" not only means "I love you," but it also means "Let's be together till we die."
> In Telugu, "**I**ntiki veltunnava?" means "Are you going home?"

What I'm wondering is whether I should capitalize the *i* in the transliteration of "*intiki veltunnava*?

In other words, which one should it be?

1. In Telugu, "**i**ntiki veltunnava?" means...
2. In Telugu, "**I**ntiki veltunnava?" means...

If Telugu had a distinction between uppercase and lowercase letters, I could just use the equivalent version in the English transliteration, but Telugu is written in an abugida script, so that isn't really applicable. The transliteration introduces a new element that I can't figure out how to resolve.

Comment: The general rule of thumb that I use is that if the quoted material is a complete sentence, capitalize/punctuate it as such, following the conventions of the language of the quoted material.

Comment: For the specific phrase in this inquiry, Telugu is normally written with a monocase abugida, so the question becomes one of following the conventions established for transliterating Telugu into the Latin alphabet.

Comment: This Q needs some tweaking, but Jeff Zeitlin has nailed it. The question  hinges on rules for transliteration of languages which do not use Latin alphabet.

Comment: I have retracted my VTC, as I think there is a good question here, once it gets cleaned up a little.

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ - I was about to do an edit after having read the comments, but you're welcome to do the cleanup if you'd like :)

Comment: @Heartspring By all means, have at it. Looking forward to your response...

Comment: @Heartspring Thanks for helping out...there are too many users here who would rather close a post that seemingly does not fit our format instead of looking for the diamond in the chaff...

Comment: I am curious to see what answers emerge, but it seems to me that, in the same way that you capitalized *Saranghe* without question at the beginning of its sentence, so should you capitalize *Intiki* at the beginning of its sentence.

Comment: Can you say why you might want to do that, or why not?